# Python program that gets my hackerrank code and scores using requests

Tags: python, beginner, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to extend my coding skills to other languages by doing projects. (learned Java in school) and since python is very popular right now thats what I ended up choosing for this project, though I'm fairly new to it. Does this code follow common best practices? Is there anything I can do to improve this program so it's more readable/ understandable.

```py
import re, json, os, requests
import browsercookie

class Hackerrank_Session:

    LOGIN_DATA = {
        'login': '',
        'password': '',
    }

    HEADERS = {
        'x-csrf-token': '',
        'cookie': '',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.157 Safari/537.36'
    }

    BASE_URL = 'https://www.hackerrank.com/'

    URL_HACKERRANK_PTS = 'https://www.hackerrank.com/domains/algorithms?filters%5Bstatus%5D%5B%5D=unsolved&badge_type=problem-solving'

    URL = ''

    SUBMISSIONS = {}

    LANGUAGE = {
        'python3': {
            'main': "if __name__ == '__main__':",
            'import': ["#!/bin/python3", "import(.*?)(\n)+"],
            'extension': "py",
            'comment': "#"
            },
        'java8': {
            'main': r"private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);",
            'import': ["", "import(.*?)(\n)+"],
            'extension': "java",
            'comment': "//"
            },
        'java': {
            'main': r"private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);",
            'import': ["", "import(.*?)(\n)+"],
            'extension': "java",
            'comment': "//"
            },
        'C': {
            'main': "int main()",
            'import': ["", "#include(.*?)(\n)+"],
            'extension': "c",
            'comment': "//"
            },
        'JavaScript': {
            'main': "function main()",
            'import': ["", "'use strict';(.*?)// Complete"],
            'extension': "js",
            'comment': "//"
            }
    }

    def __init__(self):
        return


    # Gets the needed cookies to keep a session active on www.hackerrank.com
    def getHackerrankCookies(self):
        Chrome_Cookies = str(browsercookie.chrome()._cookies)
        if not re.findall("name='hackerrank_mixpanel_token', value='(.*?)'", Chrome_Cookies) and re.findall("name='_hrank_session', value='(.*?)'", Chrome_Cookies):
            raise Exception("No Hackerrank Cookie Found. Signed In Required.")
        else: 
            cookie_hk = 'hackerrank_mixpanel_token='
            cookie_hk += re.findall("name='hackerrank_mixpanel_token', value='(.*?)'", Chrome_Cookies)[0] + '; '
            cookie_hk += '_hrank_session='
            cookie_hk += re.findall("name='_hrank_session', value='(.*?)'", Chrome_Cookies)[0] + '; '
            self.HEADERS['cookie'] = cookie_hk


    # Gets token from www.hackerrank.com 
    def getHackerrankToken(self):
        login = requests.post(self.BASE_URL + '/rest/auth/login', data = self.LOGIN_DATA )
        if re.findall('Invalid login or password', login.text): print("ERROR: Invalid login or password.")
        else: 
            if 'csrf_token' not in login.json():
                raise Exception("csrf_token not found.")
            else:
                login.json()['csrf_token']: 
                token = str(login.json()['csrf_token'])
                self.HEADERS['x-csrf-token'] = token


    # Gets www.hackerrank.com scores.
    def getScores(self):
        scores_page = requests.get(self.URL_HACKERRANK_PTS, headers=self.HEADERS)
        scores = re.findall('class="value">(.*?)<', scores_page.text)
        if not scores:
            raise Exception("No scores found.")
        return scores


    # Add the scores and rank on hackerrank to a JSON file.
    def scoresToJson(self):
        scores = self.getScores()
        scores_json = {}
        if not os.path.exists("HackerRankScores.json"): 
            with open("HackerRankScores.json", 'w') as score_json:
                score_json.write(" ")
        with open("HackerRankScores.json", 'r') as scores_file:
            scores_json = json.load(scores_file)
            last_element = (list(scores_json.keys())[-1])
            if scores_json[last_element]['rank'] == int(scores[0]) or scores_json[last_element]['points'] == int(re.split('/', scores[1])[0]): print("ERROR: JSON not updated, rank or scores value same as previous session.")
            else: 
                scores_json[str(int(last_element) + 1)] = {'rank': int(scores[0]), 'points': int(re.split('/', scores[1])[0])}
                with open("HackerRankScores.json", 'w') as scores_file:
                    json.dump(scores_json, scores_file)


    # Gets the url for the successful challenges.
    def getSubmissions(self):
        get_track =  requests.get(url='https://www.hackerrank.com/rest/contests/master/submissions/?offset=0&limit=1000', headers=self.HEADERS)
        data = json.loads(get_track.content)
        for i in range(len(data['models'])):
            name = data['models'][i]['challenge']['name']
            sub_url = 'https://www.hackerrank.com/rest/contests/master/challenges/' + data['models'][i]['challenge']['slug'] + '/submissions/' + str(data['models'][i]['id'])
            if data['models'][i]['status'] == "Accepted" and name not in self.SUBMISSIONS: self.SUBMISSIONS[name] = sub_url


    # Gets the code from successful challenges. all(bool) get either the last or all the successful submissions' code, imp(bool) write the import statements or not, main(bool) write the main function or not.
    def getCode(self, all=True, imp=False, main=False):

        # If no submissions url get the submissions.
        if len(self.SUBMISSIONS) == 0: self.getSubmissions()

        # Gets the code of the last successful submission/all the last successful submissions.
        if all: all = len(list(self.SUBMISSIONS.keys()))
        else:  all = 1
        for i in range(all):
            key = list(self.SUBMISSIONS.keys())[i]
            get_sub = requests.get(url=self.SUBMISSIONS[key], headers=self.HEADERS)
            code = get_sub.json()['model']['code']
            lang = get_sub.json()['model']['language']
            name = get_sub.json()['model']['name']
            difficulty_Url = re.split('submissions', self.SUBMISSIONS[key])[0]
            difficulty = requests.get(url=difficulty_Url, headers=self.HEADERS).json()['model']['difficulty_name']

            # Create a description of the challenge: Type of challenge - Name of track - Difficulty.
            description = get_sub.json()['model']['track']['track_name'] + " - " + name + " - " + difficulty
            code = re.sub(self.LANGUAGE[lang]['comment']+'(.*?)(\n)', '', code)

            # Remove the import tags.
            if not imp:
                code = re.sub(self.LANGUAGE[lang]['import'][0], '', code)
                code = re.sub(self.LANGUAGE[lang]['import'][1], '', code)

            # Remove the main function.
            if not main:
                code = re.split(self.LANGUAGE[lang]['main'], code)[0]

            # Checks if the corresponding language file exits in the directory.
            if not os.path.exists('hackerrank_file.' + self.LANGUAGE[lang]['extension']):
                with open('hackerrank_file.' + self.LANGUAGE[lang]['extension'], 'w') as f:
                    f.write('')

            # Checks if the challenge has already been written in the corresponding language file.
            hackerrank_file = ''
            with open('hackerrank_file.' + self.LANGUAGE[lang]['extension'], 'r') as f:
                hackerrank_file = f.read()

            # write the challenge code to the corresponding language file.
            if not name in hackerrank_file:
                code = '\n' + self.LANGUAGE[lang]['comment'] + " " + description + code
                with open('hackerrank_file.' + self.LANGUAGE[lang]['extension'] , 'a') as f:
                    f.write(code)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = Hackerrank_Session()
    s.getHackerrankCookies()
    s.getSubmissions()
    s.getCode(last=True, imp=False, main=False)
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please also include the description of what you want to accomplish also in the question, not just in the title.

Answer (score 0):

Such pile of code just "tears out my eyes" ppl say.

- all constant string must be extracted as variables and not pop up in middle of methods
- at *cookie_hk +=*  are you sure you must build string with your own format and dont use someth. directly like it is in source?
- do not repeat the same twice and try to generalize tasks end extract it to separate methods